# Finding a minimal colored graph containing all given subgraphs

Tags: graphs

I suspect this is a standard problem, but I was unable to find any literature on it -- my question is, what is the canonical formulation (and ideally solution) to the following:

> Given a set $S$ of $K$-colored graphs $\{G_i\}$, find the smallest graph $G$ by number of nodes that contains all $G_i \in S$ as subgraphs.

I've provided a basic illustration:

[image: mini example of S and corresponding G]

I do not assume a restriction where adjacent colors cannot be next to one another in any of the subgraphs. The colors are simply node distinguishability markers and can be replaced by any type of label.

Comment: "smallest" with respect to what? number of nodes? number of edges?

Comment: @nirshahar apologies, I meant smallest by number of nodes -- was lost in an edit

Comment: This problem is at least NP-hard even if there is only one color. A [clique problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem) $(G,k)$ can be answered by this problem with two subgraphs: $G$ and a $k$-clique.